# What is contents in beautifulsoup4 and the number string?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying a web scraping in bs4 and I don't know what it is, Pls Someone explain it to me tnx

```
 name = div.contents[0].string + div.contents[1]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `contents` attribute holds a list of child elements of the element.  The `.string` attribute of an element contains the text content for the element.

Using this page as an example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from pprint import pprint

resp = requests.get("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73842279/what-is-contents-in-beautifulsoup4-and-the-number-string")
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text, 'html.parser')

for elem in soup.find_all('div'):
    if elem.has_attr('id') and elem['id'].strip() == "question-header":
        pprint(elem.contents)

        pprint(elem.contents[1].string)
```

**output**  for `elem.contents`

```
['\n',
 <h1 class="fs-headline1 ow-break-word mb8 flex--item fl1" itemprop="name"><a class="question-hyperlink" href="/questions/73842279/what-is-contents-in-beautifulsoup4-and-the-number-string">What is conten
ts in beautifulsoup4 and the number string?</a></h1>,
 '\n',
 <div class="ml12 aside-cta flex--item print:d-none sm:ml0 sm:mb12 sm:order-first sm:as-end">
<a class="ws-nowrap s-btn s-btn__primary" href="/questions/ask">
        Ask Question
    </a>
</div>,
 '\n']
```

**output** for `elem.contents[1].string`

```
'What is contents in beautifulsoup4 and the number string?'
```